TemplateSyntaxError Could not parse the remainder
I have this bit of jinja2 in my Django template:
{% for filesystem, total_quota, total_usage, df_usage in totals_by_filesystem %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ filesystem }}</span></td>
    <td>{{ total_quota | filesizeformat }}</td>
    <td>{{ total_usage | filesizeformat }}</td>
    <td>{{ df_usage * 100 }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}

When I run it I get this error message:
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: ' * 100' from 'df_usage * 100'

I am pretty sure my syntax {{ df_usage * 100 }} is correct.  What am I missing here?

You could try something like: {% multiply df_usage 100 %} or {% widthratio df_usage 1 100 %}

You can not use * with Django's template language. You can use Jinja, prepare the items in the view, or use a template tag.

If there were a way to tell filesizeformat that the input is KB instead of just bytes I would do that.  Does anyone know if that is possible.  The documentation for filesizeformat is extremely terse.

Django's template language does not allow complex expressions, so {{ x * 100 }}, as simple as it seems, is not evaluated by Django.
There are essentially three options:
1. use a template tag
the {% widthratio … %} template tag [Django-doc] essentially implements the rule of three [wiki], although this is more designed for charts. It will divide by the second operand, and then multiply by the third and round the result, so:
{% widthratio df_usage 1 100 %}

divides by one (no effect) multiplies by 100 and then rounds the result.
2. prepare the result in the view
Instead of doing arithmetic in the view, which is also not very efficient, you can prepare the items in the view with:
totals_by_filesize = [
    (filesystem, total_quota, total_usage, 100 * df_usage)
    for (filesystem, total_quota, total_usage, df_usage) in totals_by_filesystem
]
3. use jinja
Django's template language does not support several features, this has been done deliberately to prevent people from writing business logic in the templates. One can use Jinja as a template language, but this is not necessary and to some extent counterproductive, precisely to prevent writing business logic in the template.

Thanks! I didn't know that Django's templates were not Jinja templates. I went with option 2 BTW

One way is to add a template filter without having to prepare it in the view.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#how-to-create-custom-template-tags-and-filters
multiplication in django template without using manually created template tag
